# Remove all rows that are duplicates with respect to some rows

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've seen a couple questions like this but not a satisfactory answer for my situation. Here is a sample DataFrame:

```
+------+-----+----+
|    id|value|type|
+------+-----+----+
|283924|  1.5|   0|
|283924|  1.5|   1|
|982384|  3.0|   0|
|982384|  3.0|   1|
|892383|  2.0|   0|
|892383|  2.5|   1|
+------+-----+----+
```

I want to identify duplicates by just the `"id"` and `"value"` columns, and then remove all instances.

In this case:

- Rows 1 and 2 are duplicates (again we are ignoring the "type" column)
- Rows 3 and 4 are duplicates, and therefore only rows 5 & 6 should remain:

The output would be:

```
+------+-----+----+
|    id|value|type|
+------+-----+----+
|892383|  2.5|   1|
|892383|  2.0|   0|
+------+-----+----+
```

I've tried

```
df.dropDuplicates(subset = ['id', 'value'], keep = False)
```

But the "keep" feature isn't in PySpark (as it is in [`pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

How else could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the window functions

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F
df.withColumn(
  'fg', 
  F.count("id").over(Window.partitionBy("id", "value"))
).where("fg = 1").drop("fg").show()
```

Comment: I thought that this would be equivalent to my answer, but the execution plan says otherwise.

Comment: When I do this, I still get the original row count. No change

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupBy` the `id` and `type` to get the count. Then use `join` to filter out the rows in your DataFrame where the count is not 1:

```python
df.join(
    df.groupBy('id', 'value').count().where('count = 1').drop('count'), on=['id', 'value']
).show()
#+------+-----+----+
#|    id|value|type|
#+------+-----+----+
#|892383|  2.5|   1|
#|892383|  2.0|   0|
#+------+-----+----+
```

Comment: When I do this, I still get the original row count. No change

Comment: Both this answer and @Steven's below work for me. Can you create a [mcve] that shows your issue?

Comment: I'm sorry, I created a new dataframe and used your solutions, both worked. It seems my original data has been augmented by another party and the data not de-duping as expected is because the data is no longer the same. That is my fault.