# Pyspark drop_duplicates(keep=False)

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, duplicates

i need a **Pyspark** solution for Pandas `drop_duplicates(keep=False)`. Unfortunately, the `keep=False` option is not available in pyspark...

**Pandas Example:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_data = {'A': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar'], 
         'B': [3, 3, 5],
         'C': ['one', 'two', 'three']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A', 'B'], keep=False)
print(df)
```

*Expected output:*

```
     A  B       C
2  bar  5  three
```

A conversion `.to_pandas()` and back to pyspark is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Groupby ['A', 'B'], get the count of groups, and remove all groups with size > 1. Not sure how to do this with pyspark but that's how I'd do it in the absence of `keep=False`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all rows that are duplicates with respect to some rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522719/remove-all-rows-that-are-duplicates-with-respect-to-some-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use window function to count the number of rows for each `A / B` combination, and then filter the result to keep only rows that are unique:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.selectExpr(
  '*', 
  'count(*) over (partition by A, B) as cnt'
).filter(f.col('cnt') == 1).drop('cnt').show()

+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|    C|
+---+---+-----+
|bar|  5|three|
+---+---+-----+
```

Or another option using `pandas_udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

# keep_unique returns the data frame if it has only one row, otherwise 
# drop the group
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def keep_unique(df):
    return df.iloc[:0] if len(df) > 1 else df

df.groupBy('A', 'B').apply(keep_unique).show()
+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|    C|
+---+---+-----+
|bar|  5|three|
+---+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to count such rows and then select only those with have one occurrence to avoid any row from duplicates and then drop the extra column.

```
df= df.groupBy('A', 'B').agg(f.expr('count(*)').alias('Frequency'))
df=df.select('*').where(df.Frequency==1)
df=df.drop('Frequency')
```